# Using Flexbox. Site broken with nav bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am constructing a basic site with HTML5 and use FlexBox. As you can see here:

[image]

the "What does WWF" do text is between the navbar ul and `<aside>` element. I want it to be directly below the navbar. How do I fix this?

Relevant code snippet:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header style="height: 150px">
    <img src="placeholdr">
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>About</a></li>
      <li><a>School</a></li>
      <li><a>Workplace</a></li>
      <li><a>Girlfriend</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="flex">
    <section id="content">
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1>What Does WWF Do?</h1>
          <p>WWF's mission:</p>
        </header>
        <p>the text</p>
        <p>text</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <aside>
      <img src="placeholdrr">
    </aside>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `position:absolute` style to a main `nav` so that you can add a `position:relative` so it can go under.

Basically the `position:absolute` will say where is the "main" tag positioned so it can be relative to something. Maybe this will help.

I'm to this, at least I tried to help :p

Answer (score 0):

If all the sections (direct children) inside your 'id="wrapper"' div have a width of 100% they will naturally be placed under each other in the same order as your DOM, e.g.

header
nav
div
footer

Alternatively, you can make your 'id="wrapper"' into a flex display with "flex-direction: column;"